# Adding time in Serial Monitor

Tags: arduino-uno

I need help in my Arduino project. I am trying to add the current time in Serial Monitor but i couldnt make it happen... I was also trying to do something like this...[image]

Here is my current code right now...

```cpp
// Purpose: To monitor the room temperature
// Programmer: Emmanuel Quiambao Sr.
// Date: Nov. 26, 2019

#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

// set the current time
// Set temperature parameter
const int hot = 85;
const int cold = 70;
const int motorPin = 7;
int switchState = 0;

void setup () {

  pinMode(A0, INPUT); // Temp sensor
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT); // Green Led
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT); // Yellow Led
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT); // Red Led
  pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT); // Fan 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port
  Serial.println("Time Voltage Temperature");

 }

void loop(){

  int sensor = analogRead(A0);
  float voltage = (sensor / 1024.0) * 5.0;
  float tempC = (voltage - .5) * 100;
  float tempF = (tempC * 1.8) + 32;
  int reading = analogRead(A0);
  unsigned long curMillis = millis( );  // get current time

  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(voltage);
  Serial.print(" \volts");
  Serial.print(tempF);
  Serial.print(" \F");

  Serial.print(curMillis);
  Serial.println( );
  delay(100);

  if (tempF < cold)            // Too cold
  {
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  lcd.setCursor(1,0);
  lcd.print(" Too Cold "); // print results to lcd
  lcd.setCursor(1,1);
  lcd.print(tempF,1);
  lcd.print("F");           // print results to lcd 
  }

  else if (tempF >= hot)      // Too hot
  {
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0);
  lcd.print(" It's Hot "); // print results to lcd
  lcd.setCursor(1,1);
  lcd.print(tempF,1);
  lcd.print("F");           // print results to lcd
  }

  else                        // Desired temperature
  {
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0);
  lcd.print(" It's Fine "); // print results to lcd
  lcd.setCursor(1,1);
  lcd.print(tempF,1);
  lcd.print("F");           // print results to lcd

   switchState = digitalRead(9);  
  if (switchState == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH);
  }
  }

  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: What would be the time source for your Arduino? Do you have an RTC hooked up?

Comment: Sir, I just want to add the current time. also if possible maybe you can help me in fixing the columns of it like the one in the photo that i attached. i would like if possible to be "TIME VOLTAGE TEMPERATURE". I appreciate your prompt response.

Comment: I attached the temp sensor only. I apologize for my ignorance I am new to this project; what is RTC?

Comment: A [real time clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock). It's a device that can tell your Arduino what time it is.

Comment: Ow, i do not have that in my kit... just a question do I need an RTC if i just want to add the time in Serial Monitor? I just want to record the change of temperature every 10 secs?